# Ubuntu 11.10 crashes on boot shows busybox

Tags: 11.10, boot

When i boot into ubuntu 11.10 it shows only a black screen stating

```
busybox built in shell (ash)"
Enter'help' for list of keyword
```

It was a fresh install,Installed some basic componets such as 'Ubuntu restricted extras' and 'vlc media player' and 'adobe flash'
Real problem is I cannot boot into ubuntu instead it boots me up in busybox shell.

Comment: Did you upgrade your computer? Is this a fresh install? What are the last things that you installed? Have you made any changes recently? We'd need more details to tell you what the real problem is. The best I can figure from this is that you've managed to delete a key system file and it's booting to recovery mode.

Comment: similar question,here is the link to answer
visit http://askubuntu.com/questions/44286/busybox-error-on-boot/44288#44288

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and as such is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had similar problems and they depended on my cdrom.
Try to login in recovery mode. If you get stuck with some message regarding SATA
then CD-Rom is your problem. For me it has been enough to remove it and everything has kept working fine then.