# *-network UNCLAIMED after software update on dell xps 13

Tags: 14.04, drivers, network-manager, dell, update-manager

I recently got a new Dell xps 13 developer edition with Ubuntu 14.04. Since I got a software update my wireless network device has stopped working. lshw -C network gives:

> *-network UNCLAIMED
>
> ```
>    description: Network controller
>    product: Wireless 8260
>    vendor: Intel Corporation
>    physical id: 0
>    bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
>    version: 3a
>    width: 64 bits
>    clock: 33MHz
>    capabilities: cap_list
>    configuration: latency=0
>    resources: memory:dc200000-dc201fff
> ```

The additional drivers tab in the settings menu also seems to be stuck on "Do not use this device", even though it shows other drivers. When I try to change the driver, I am unable to do so. This laptop does not have a Ethernet port.

This is my first time using Linux, so a clearly explained answer would be helpful. So far I have tried other solutions which I could find for similar problem, but to no avail.

As requested: 
When checked in `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 0050` it gives:
`alias: pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00_0050_90bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00_0050_2Abc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00_0050_20bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00_0050_02bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00_0050_0Abc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00_0050_00bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00_0050_12bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d0000095Asv*sd00_0050_10bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00_0050_72bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d000008B1sv*sd00_0050_70bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00_0050_27bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00_0050_25bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00_0050_17bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d00000897sv*sd00_0050_15bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00_0050_07bc*sc*i*
alias: pci:v00008086d00000896sv*sd00_0050_05bc*sc*i*`

Comment: What is the exact response to the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` ?

Comment: @chili555  "sudo modprobe iwlwifi" does not give a response.

Comment: Let's dig a little deeper: `dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 "dmesg | grep iwl" doesn't give a response either...

Comment: Wow! Are you certain this device worked at first? I wonder if this is a Dell-specific driver tweak. May we see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and also: uname -r`

Comment: @chili555 "Uname -r' " gives:  `>`, with nothing else showing up, not even a new :~$...                      When I tried `uname -r` it gave: `3.19.0-66-generic`

Comment: @chili555 `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` gives: `3a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev3) Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:00550] 3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:525a] (rev 1)`

Comment: How about:  `sudo updatedb && locate oem-wireless` updatedb will take a few moments, please be patient. Finally: `dmesg | grep dkms`

Comment: @chili555 `sudo updatedb && locate oem-wireless` gives nothing.                   `dmesg | grep dkms` gives nothing as well

Comment: Please recheck: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Is the subsystem 0055 or 0550 or ... what? Whatever it is, check this: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep 0550` or whatever subsystem you found. I suspect the problem is that it is not covered at all without a Dell-specific tweak we've been unable to uncover and therefore fix so far.

Comment: If you find that the correct subsystem is not covered by the 3.19.0-xx version of the driver *iwlwifi*, I will propose a solution!

Comment: @chili555 My mistake, it was supposed to be 0050. The response is too long for a comment. I put it in with the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please notice your pci.id (corrected):

> Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev3) Subsystem: Intel
>   Corporation Device [8086:0050]

For the driver *iwlwifi* to claim and drive your device, it must find a match in the module alias fields that match, exactly, 8086:24f3 AND 0050. In the *modinfo* you posted, there are several references to 0050 but none to 24f3. Here is the corresponding data from my machine running kernel version 4.4.0-xx:

```
chili@T440p:~$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep 0050
alias:          pci:v00008086d000024F3sv*sd00000050bc*sc*i*
<snip>
```

As you can see, there is an exact match.

I believe there are three possible solutions to your issue. First, you could contact Dell and report that their apparent driver tweak that enabled your wireless to work at first was obliterated by an update; probably a later kernel version. They might have a solution and might email a revised tweak package. We have seen other instances of oem-wireless-dkms packages from Dell that fail after a kernel update.

Second, you could reboot, interrupt the boot process at the GRUB menu and select the earliest kernel you have. Boot into it and enjoy your wireless. However, that process would be required at every boot.

[image]

This is an older example but illustrates how you could boot, in the example, into -12 instead of -14.

Third, you could install a later kernel version that properly drives your device.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial
```

After a reboot, you will be running kernel version 4.4.0-x and your wireless will be working.

Although you may select any option, I suggest that the third option is the simplest and preferred option.

Comment: Thank you for the awnsers. I assume i need to get a network connection first for option 3 to work?

Comment: I'm afraid none of the kernels in the list returned wifi functionality. Since I haven't had this laptop for too long, I think I will just use the restore system option and install the 4.4.0-x kernel immediately after.

Comment: If you are unable to borrow a USB wireless or ethernet, I can edit my answer to add off-line instructions.

Comment: I've already reset the laptop, and wifi is working for now. However, when I run `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial` it ends with: `E: Unable to locate package linux-generic-lts-xenial`

Comment: Please first try: `sudo apt-get update` and then: `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` worked fine, but `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-xenial` returned the same as before.

Comment: Please open *Software and Updates*. Be certain that main, universe, restricted, and universe are selected. If not, please do and then try again. If this doesn't work, I will edit to write off-line instructions.

Comment: It looks like this did the trick, but after a reboot it opens "BusyBox", which I can't seem to exit.

Comment: Busybox??? What does it say, exactly, on the screen? A terminal prompt or what? Like this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/44286/busybox-error-on-boot

Comment: here's what it says exactly:
`BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs) *prompt*`

Comment: That typically indicates a corrupted file system which you can attempt to repair from the prompt. It is beyond my experience level. I suggest you search askubuntu for remedies.

Comment: I tried to follow the above steps suggested by chili555 and used the third option he suggested, which is to install later kernel and that fixed my wifi issues. However, now I can't seem to connect to wired connection now. How can I fix this? I was able to connect to wired connection without any problem before installing the later kernel.

Comment: @SaiCharan Please start your own new question and we'll be happy to help.