# BusyBox at 17.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, 17.04, busybox

So I have dual boot (win + ubuntu), I shrinked Ubuntu partition, and added these GB's to mine Win partition (through windows disk management), now it shows busybox. Gparted made everything successfully without any errors, system was working fine, but today when I tried to boot it - BusyBox.
Please don't mark this as duplicate because there's no clear answer to this frustrating thing.
Tried boot-repair, did nothing.

Some outputs:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA WDC WD10EZEX-08M (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size   Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  630GB   630GB  primary   ext4
 2      630GB   842GB   212GB  extended               lba
 5      630GB   842GB   212GB  logical   ntfs
 3      842GB   842GB   105MB  primary   ntfs
 4      842GB   1000GB  158GB  primary   ntfs         boot


Model: SanDisk Cruzer Blade (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4005MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  4005MB  4003MB  primary  fat32        boot, lb
```

a

**/var/log/boot.log** file

```
stdin: Not a typewriter
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
Generation complete.
pwconv: failed to change the mode of /etc/passwd- to 0600
Using CD-ROM mount point /cdrom/
Identifying... [f8a7462a6e6017e4f995aa3cfc2ac6a9-2]
Scanning disc for index files...
Found 2 package indexes, 0 source indexes, 0 translation indexes and 1 signatures
Found label 'Ubuntu 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412)'
This disc is called: 
'Ubuntu 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412)'
Copying package lists...gpgv: Signature made Wed Apr 12 03:43:31 2017 UTC
gpgv:                using RSA key 
gpgv: Good signature from "Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>"

Reading Package Indexes... 0%

Reading Package Indexes... Done

Writing new source list
Source list entries for this disc are:
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 17.04 _Zesty Zapus_ - Release amd64 (20170412)]/ zesty main restricted
Repeat this process for the rest of the CDs in your set.
[9;0]
```

**Fsck**

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ fsck
fsck from util-linux 2.29
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

**Booting errors:**

[image]

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ fsck -a /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.29
fsck.ext2: Permission denied while trying to open /dev/sda1
You must have r/w access to the filesystem or be root
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ su -
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck -a /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.29
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/sda1: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  

/dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
    (i.e., without -a or -p options)
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ fsck /dev/sda1 
fsck from util-linux 2.29
e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
fsck.ext2: Permission denied while trying to open /dev/sda1
You must have r/w access to the filesystem or be root
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fsck /dev/sda1 
fsck from util-linux 2.29
e2fsck 1.43.4 (31-Jan-2017)
/dev/sda1 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 258 was part of the orphaned inode list.  FIXED.
Inode 611 extent block passes checks, but checksum does not match extent
    (logical block 512, physical block 40361984, len 529)
Fix<y>? yes
Inode 784 extent block passes checks, but checksum does not match extent
    (logical block 13, physical block 1748389, len 465)
Fix<y>? yes
Deleted inode 1680 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23341766 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23342389 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Fix<y>? yes
Inode 23469229 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Fix<y>? yes
Deleted inode 25952265 has zero dtime.  Fix<y>? yes
Pass 1E: Optimizing extent trees
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences:  -9780 -9793 -(40407568--40407570) -(40511114--40511129) -(40511131--40511145) -(40511147--40511163) -(40511165--40511178) -(40511180--40511199) -(40511201--40511214) -(40511216--40511233) -(40511235--40511250) -(40511252--40511274) -(40511276--40511289) -(40511291--40511308) -(40511310--40511323) -(40511325--40511344) -(40511346--40511360) -(40511362--40511379) -(40511381--40511394) -(40511396--40511408) -(40679424--40681471) -(40685568--40687615) -(40691712--40693759) -(40697856--40699903) -(40704000--40706047) -(40710144--40711067)
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #0 (95, counted=97).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1233 (1433, counted=1436).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1236 (10240, counted=10519).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1241 (0, counted=6144).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong for group #1242 (0, counted=5020).
Fix<y>? yes
Free blocks count wrong (99499195, counted=99510643).
Fix<y>? yes
Inode bitmap differences:  -258 -1680 -25952265
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #0 (22, counted=24).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong for group #3168 (8142, counted=8143).
Fix<y>? yes
Free inodes count wrong (38097865, counted=38097868).
Fix<y>? yes

/dev/sda1: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****
/dev/sda1: 355380/38453248 files (0.3% non-contiguous), 54284173/153794816 blocks
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I tried everything and one dude found a solution (at least it worked for me)

> Looks like there's some problem with the ext filesystem these days...
>   because this is the 4th time i get this question in the last 2 weeks.
>   (from friends and now from here).
>
> My guess is that you have the filesystem corrupted or broken in any
>   way, but it's easy to fix, don't worry ;-)
>
> Everything can be done from the Ubuntu live CD. Boot from there, and
>   check which one is the partition where you have ubuntu installed on
>   (sda1, sda5...). You can do it easily using Gparted. Even from there,
>   you can right click on the partition and select "verify".
>
> If you want to do it from the command line, just type:
>
> `fsck /dev/sda1` (being sda1 the partition where you have ubuntu
>   installed).
>
> And it will fix the ext4 filesystem problems. If you're getting too
>   much questions while using it, add the "-a" switch to it:
>
> `fsck -a /dev/sda1`
>
> I have to tell you that use this with precaution. If the data is
>   sensitive there, first make a backup if you can from the livecd to
>   someplace else.
>
> After the filesystem is fixed, you should be able to boot normally in
>   ubuntu again.
>
> Hope this helps you with that.

- David Rando

Original answer: *[Busybox error on boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44286/busybox-error-on-boot)*
Thanks!